# Is it possible to get GIMP 2.10.4 work on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, dependencies, compiling, gimp

I tried to install it from source, but there some dependencies problems, a lot and I don't know how to get them - it seems like they not in repo.
Could you get GIMP 2.10.4 work on your Ubuntu 16.04 ? How to install (and where to get them) all necessary for dependencies ?

Comment: Gimp 2.10.0 is available as a snap.   It's possible the glib/gtk+ libs in 16.04 are tool old for Gimp 2.10.x, so snaps where they are contained within a possibly the easiest. A later version than 2.10.0 may be available; I haven't looked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that the glib/GTK+ libs in 16.04 are too old for Gimp 2.10.x, so snaps; where libraries (& other dependencies) are contained within [the snap] are possibly the easiest option.

2.10.0 is available as a snap (https://snapcraft.io/gimp), which will auto-update to a later snap if/when later releases are 'snapped'.

--

Joey Sneddon showed Gimp 2.10.4 is available via Flathub

article: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/07/gimp-2-10-4-released-with-faster-start-times-auto-straighten-tool

GIMP on Flathub : https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gimp.GIMP

Also from Joey Sneddon's article, the unofficial GIMP AppImage or Otto Kesselgulasch's GIMP PPA can provide later versions (2.10.3 & 2.10.2)

2.10.3 unofficial GIMP AppImage https://github.com/aferrero2707/gimp-appimage

2.10.2 Otto Kesselggulasch's GIMP PPA: https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp

Answer (score 3):

## Use Snappy

Typically the latest versions of the apps like Gimp are not in the older but still supported versions of Ubuntu such as 16.04 LTS. This may be due to dependency or other potential problems.

Canonical's solution to this problem is [Snappy package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(package_manager)). The Snappy sub-system is built into the newer versions of Ubuntu. Snap packages can be installed by either GUI or command line.

## Install by GUI

Open **Ubuntu Software** and search for gimp:

[image]

Now click on the description of Gimp to expand it, and scroll to the bottom.

[image]

Note, the gimp version number and developer. If satisfied, click on <kbd>Install</kbd> and provide the your password when prompted.

One thing is about snap packages is that they are rather large. This is because they are self contained, and have all the dependencies stored inside the package. Each snap app runs in its own sandbox.

Snap apps will automatically update to the latest build as soon as the developed makes the updated snap package available. So, even if it says gimp 10.0.0 now, it will get updated when the the latest version becomes available in this format.

## Install by Command line

To search for a software in the snappy repositories open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
snap find gimp
```

You will see something like:

```
Name  Version  Developer     Notes  Summary
gimp  2.10.0   snapcrafters  -      GNU Image Manipulation Program
```

Use the following command to install gimp:

```
sudo snap install gimp
```

Enter your password when prompted. Unlike the GUI, the cursor won't move and there won't be any `*`s as you type. This is normal in Ubuntu command line password prompt.

Also see this [OMG Ubuntu story](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/gimp-2-10-ubuntu-download) from a couple of months ago for other ways to install gimp.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, but currently snap provedes 2.10.0 while flatpak provides 2.10.4 - just like GIMP's homepage.

Comment: You are welcome. `flatpack` is an alternative to `snap`. Like PPA repositories, `snap` packages are updated more frequently and the `gimp` `snap` will get updated soon. If you install 2.10 in snap now you will automatically get 2.10.4 when it becomes available in `snap`.